# List of Truth Questions

Tags: discussion

I'm just listing a couple of book titles by Calvinist theologian R.C. Sproul.

- Can I trust the Bible?
- Does prayer change things?
- Can I know God's will?
- How should I live in God's world?
- Can I be sure I'm saved?
- What can I do with my guilt?
- Can I enjoy joy in my life?
- Does God control everything?

Essentially, if a question is about a person's laying his or her own opinions on how you should live your life, then it's a truth question. If a question is about a person's laying his or her opinions on what God is, what God likes and dislikes, and how you should appease God, then it's a truth question.

Fortunately, the good news (LOL!) is that truth questions can all be answered by finding the appropriate theologian or theology. In this case, Sproul is a Calvinist theologian, so he may report things with a Reformed bias. For example, one of the things he says about human nature is that human nature is *totally spiritually dead*. In addition, his understanding of the Trinity is strongly Trinitarian, and he provides supporting examples of the Holy Trinity, even treating the Holy Spirit as a person -- something a Jehovah's Witness would probably not do!

The question "Can I trust the Bible?" is a truth question that borders on pastoral advice, and a pastor will most likely say, "Yes." I do not think this type of truth question can be manipulated into a non-truth question, because the word "trust" is personal and subjective. A non-truth question regarding Calvinist prayer may be, "How does intercessory prayer work in Calvinism where there are no saints for intercession?" or "How do Calvinists recognize people with exceptional holiness without resorting to the canon of saints?"

In summary, some truth questions can be manipulated into non-truth questions, but truth questions that border on pastoral advice can be treated with consultation from a theology book or the expertise of a pastor/priest/minister.<sup>1</sup>

---

<sub>1. Some pastors, priests, and ministers may not be so informed in the topic that you are interested in. In that case, you're on your own.</sub>

Comment: It would be nice if someone smarter than me were to write a blog post for the many common truth questions and point people to the blog post when their answers get closed - mostly explaining why we cannot give an answer.

Comment: @TheFreemason Given that SE support for blogs has been withdrawn, I guess that dream won't come true.

Comment: Do you always reply to posts that are almost 3 years old?